# How to parse JSON multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, multidimensional-array

i have this array

```
{
    "sEcho": 1,
    "iTotalRecords": 54,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 54,
    "aaData": [
        [
            "79",
            "testowy2",
            "testowy samochod",
            "12.00",
            "14.00",
            "2147483647",
            "posciel",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

how I can parse last array with JSON in javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a unparsed object, You can use [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse it and get a object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('{ "sEcho": 1, "iTotalRecords": 54, "iTotalDisplayRecords": 54, "aaData": [ [ "79", "testowy2", "testowy samochod", "12.00", "14.00", "2147483647", "posciel", "" ] ] }');
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vdn75/1/)

Comment: How I can display data from 1st post?

Comment: @user3211948, then you can use `obj.sEcho`, or `obj.iTotalRecords`- did you check my demo?

Comment: Yes I checked it displays data in aaData but how I can separate each value in this data?

Comment: @user3211948 Since aaData is a array with a array inside, you first need to use `aaData[0]` to reach the inner array, then use numbers from `0` to reach the one you want. For example `aaData[0][3]` will give you `"12.00"`

Comment: It works thanks. Can you tell me one more thing. How can I check how many arrays are in aaData?

Comment: @user3211948, great! You can click to accept the answerif it solved your problem. About the number of arrays you can use `.length`. Keep in mind that you have array inside array. Check this demo: __http://jsfiddle.net/Vdn75/3/__

Comment: Thank you very much :) Can I convert unparse object into string?

Comment: @user3211948, yes, but that is what you have already... Anyway, check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Ye but I want to automatically when I get unparse object convert it into a string. Okey I used stringify and it works I think. Thanks again man :)

Comment: @user3211948 do you know how to see console in the browser?

Comment: @user3211948 If it is unparsed it is already a string(!). I don't understand what you mean, check here and look at the console log: http://jsfiddle.net/eK4X8/

Comment: I have unparse object like in first post then use JSON.stringify(unparseobject) and next parse this stringify. It works for me but one question. Is it good?

Comment: @user3211948, just parse the original unparsed object. Otherwise it will escape characters and you cannot parse it. Check here: __http://jsfiddle.net/68CmB/__ - and notice you don't get a object anymore. Then you need to do double work: `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(obj))`...

Comment: Okey I get it. I want to display only unique array but it only shows to 3rd row. http://jsfiddle.net/68CmB/1/

Comment: @user3211948, can you chat?

Comment: @user3211948, aha, sorry you cannot yet. Needs 20 reputation, anyway, 2 problems in your fiddle, will update in 1 min.

Comment: @user3211948, no. It's the if() statement's blame. If you remove it it does: http://jsfiddle.net/68CmB/4/

Comment: I want to show only unique data when name is repeated dont show it.

Comment: @user3211948, then what you need is to filter the array with only unique elements. I am at work and can't make you a demo, but if you ask that you will get a answer in less than 2 minutes :) Otherwise I can answer you later also...

Comment: When will you have a time? ;d